# add external data with VBA into excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In current excel sheets I work with with data import/refresh via ODBC connection where I import data from our ERP system into excel 2010. When refreshing data to excel, the existing data is deleted and replaced with the newly imported data.
Now I want to create a log file, so im looking for a way to add data to the already imported and existing data in the excel sheet. The import data properties do not offer me that functionality. Any suggestions to implement this with VBA / Macro?
Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Refresh table in TAB1, copy table to next available line in TAB2. Use TAB2 as main table.

Comment: Or... use ADODB to fetch results into an `ADODB.Recordset` and then use the `CopyFromRecordset` method of an excel `Range` to drop the data into your workbook. [Plenty of examples online](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+adodb+copyfromrecordset+example+vba&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS785US785&oq=simple+adodb+copyfromrecordset+example+vba)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions,  will try to get this to work.